# Use superscripts in text with paste (for a vector of several values) in R

Tags: r, expression, paste, subscript, superscript

I want labels with superscripts in my legend. Furthermore, I want to construct the labels with paste function. I have figured out how to have a legend that uses my vector of values using `paste`. I have also used `expression` to get superscripts. But I can't use them together.

Here are my attempts:

A plot with the legend successfully plotting three legend items based on a vector of values but no superscript in legend.

```
#set-up
size=c(50, 100, 150)
paste(size, "km^2", sep=" ")
#output: paste function works
# "50 km^2"  "100 km^2" "150 km^2"

#plot sample graph
plot(x=c(1:10)*100, y=c(1:10)*10, col="red")
points(x=c(8:17)*50, y=c(1:10)*7, col="green")
points(x=c(8:17)*50, y=c(1:10)*12, col="blue")
#legend
legend(x = 'topleft', 
       legend = paste(size, "km^2", sep=" "),
       col = c("red", "green", "blue"), pch=19,bty = 'n', xjust = 1, cex=0.8)
```

And here I can print with superscripts on the graph but without paste.

```
#print with superscript
mtext(line=-4,adj=0,expression('km'^'2'*' size '))
```

**FAILED GRAPHS**

[image]

Comment: If you just need squares,  why not use the Unicode character for square  `km²`

Comment: @G5W Could you expand on that?  I am not familar with Unicode characters and my google searching is not getting me anything that works out

Comment: You can cut and paste the character,  either from my comment `km²` OR just google to find them.  For example, Wikipedia has a page on [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)  Just cut and paste the ones you need. x²  x³ x⁴ x⁵ x⁶ x⁷ x⁸ x⁹  Paste it into your legend statement.

Comment: `legend(x = 'topleft', 
       legend = paste(size, 'km² size ', sep=" "),
       col = c("red", "green", "blue"), pch=19, bty = 'n', xjust = 1, cex=0.8)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a vector of expression strings using `paste` and then `parse` them.

```
plot(x=c(1:10)*100, y=c(1:10)*10, col="red")
points(x=c(8:17)*50, y=c(1:10)*7, col="green")
points(x=c(8:17)*50, y=c(1:10)*12, col="blue")

#legend
legend(x = 'topleft', 
       legend = parse(text=paste(size, "*km^2~size")),
       col = c("red", "green", "blue"), pch=19, bty = 'n', xjust = 1, cex=0.8)
```

[image]